# Exception thrown by IJawsRenderer()

Tags: c++, pdf, xps, mako-sdk

I’m using the Mako SDK and IJawsRenderer::render() to render all IDOMPathNodes with an IDOMImageBrush fill. When I do, the renderer throws an error 2000 exception for some nodes, but not all. What could be the cause?

```
IDOMBrushPtr pBrush;
pPath->getFill(pBrush);
if (pBrush)
{
    IDOMBrush::eBrushType fillStyle = pBrush->getBrushType();
    switch (fillStyle)
    {
    case IDOMBrush::eImage:
    {
        IJawsRendererPtr renderer = IJawsRenderer::create(jawsMako);
        IDOMImagePtr renderedImage;
        renderedImage = renderer->render(pNode, 800); // This is where the exception will eventually happen.
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the exception is thrown because the path passed to the renderer is too small. There is a lower limit of 1pt x 1pt (or 1.33 x 1.33 Mako units) for the renderer. Modify your code to check that the bounding box of the node is big enough, for example:

```
const double minimumRenderSize = 96.0 / 72.0;
...
IDOMBrushPtr pBrush;
pPath->getFill(pBrush);
FRect box;
pPath->getBounds(box);
box.dX = box.dX < minimumRenderSize ? minimumRenderSize : box.dX;
box.dY = box.dY < minimumRenderSize ? minimumRenderSize : box.dY;
if (pBrush)
{
    IDOMBrush::eBrushType fillStyle = pBrush->getBrushType();
    switch (fillStyle)
    {
    case IDOMBrush::eImage:
    {
        IJawsRendererPtr renderer = IJawsRenderer::create(jawsMako);
        IDOMImagePtr renderedImage;
        renderedImage = renderer->render(pNode, 800, IDOMColorSpacesRGB::create(jawsMako), box);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```